# why the result of lookupsymbols api are different?

Tags: .net, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I will get symbols of  local variables in the method body,so I use semanticModel.LookupSymbols.but the result have nothing about local vars.
the code is:

```
var workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
var solution = workspace.OpenSolutionAsync(soluPath).Result;
var doc = solution.Projects[0].Documents[0];
var tree = doc.getSyntaxTreeASync().Result;
var semanticModel = doc.getSemanticModelASync().Result;
var symbols = semanticModel.LookupSymbols(tree.Length);
```

but if I try another way,the result have it.the code is:

```
var tree=SyntaxFactory.ParseSyntaxTree(source);
var compilation = VisualBasicCompilation.Create("m",new []{tree},new[]{mscorlib});
var semanticModel = compilation.GetSemanticModel(tree);
var symbols=model.LookupSymbols(tree.Length);
```

The sample source:

```
Class C
End Class
Moudle Program
    Private i As Integer = 0

    Public Sub Main()
        DIm j as Integer = 0 : j += i
    End Sub
End Module
```

the first code output:

```
C
Program
Public Sub Main()
```

the second code output:

```
C
j
Microsoft
Private i As Integer
Program
Public Sub Main()
System
Windows
```

My target is local variable "j".
  what are they differences?
thanks~

Comment: What's different? What were you expecting to see, and what did you actually see?

Comment: `tree.Length` is not going to have any useful symbols.

Comment: If tree.Length is unhelpful,what the parameter should be？

Comment: That parameter is the location at which you're trying to look up what symbols are available. So by passing in `tree.Length` you're asking "What symbols are available at the very last character in the file".

Answer (score 1):

There are two things going on here:

1. The parameter you're giving tree.Length is the location you're querying for. Your local variables aren't visible from that location.
2. Your compilations must be messed up for one code sample, or the other, or both. When you have the compilations, call GetDiagnostics() and see if other things look like they're wrong. It's possible you didn't get references hooked up in the MSBuildWorkspace case for some reason.